# Convert string to datetime in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some fields suppose to be datetime but some date values are inserted as string from the application so now the fields become mixed data type. The string format is like below:
"Tue May 13 00:00:00 CDT 2010".

I am trying to convert all the string type of the date to be datetime, I am using the following format, using CreateDate as the sample field with this problem:

```
db.Test.aggregate([
    { "$addFields": {
        "$CreateDate": { 
            "$dateFromString": { 
                "dateString": "$CreateDate",
                timezone: "America/Chicago"
            } 
        }
    } }
])
```

But I am getting the following error:

errmsg" : "Error parsing date string 'Tue May 13 00:00:00 CDT 2010'"

I am using Mongo 3.6 version and format seems to be new in 4.0 only. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** store Date/Time values as string, use proper `Date` object. Your problem is yet another example of the validity of this statement.

Mongo version 4 would not help either. Month names are not supported, see [Format Specifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#std-label-dateFromString-format-specifiers)

I think you have to go for a 3rd party library, e.g. [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) but you cannot use it directly, i.e. `db.Test.aggregate([{$set: {CreateDate: moment("$CreateDate").toDate()}}])`

You could correct wrong values with a loop like this:

```
db.Test.find({ CreateDate: { $not: { $type: "date" } } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    let d = moment(doc.CreateDate).toDate();
    db.Test.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { CreateDate: d } });    
})
```

Comment: Yeah. The data was input from the front end by some development code (not me) and unfortunately I have to clean them up. Mongodb doesn't really prevent from the DB side what data type of the column so that is the problem.  Or is there anyway I can query those bad data out? Like I want to query the collection with the result of only CreateDate is string type instead of datetime type.

Comment: Can you show me some examples how to use moment.js?

Comment: Yes, you have to ensure proper data type in your application or with [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). Please see my update.

Comment: How do I import the moment.js library? I am getting the following error when using your example: 

Error:
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: moment is not defined :
@(shell):2:9
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:494:9
@(shell):1:1

Comment: Use `load("moment.js")`, see [load()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/load/)

Comment: Thanks. I am getting this error: Error: error loading js file: moment.js :
@(shell):1:1

Comment: You have to put the entire path where you stored the file.

Comment: I see. Now I need to find all the date datatype for this column and then I will need to convert them to string instead. How do I identify all the documents with that field entered as date datatype?

Comment: Seriously? Simply skip the `{$not: }`

Comment: Can you give me the full example? I just used compare to get all the date value like this: {$gte: ISODate("1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") . But I think there should be a way to just locate the value based on the data type.

Comment: Come on! `{ CreateDate: { $type: "date" } }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I need to use this tip to remove the bad data that from any array. I used the following code: db.Test.remove([
   {$unwind: "$arraylist"},
   {$match: { 'arraylist.CreateDate': {$not : {$type: "date"}}}}
  ])
I am getting errors :Expected type object but found array. How should I remove the documents to fix the condition with array  ?

Comment: You mixed https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/ with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/ Please provide a real sample of your input data, then I can help you.

Comment: Do you want to delete the entire document or only the array elements with wrong date?

Comment: I want to learn both ways. I tried $pull and also failed.  For deleting the whole document query, to delete the entire document, if the dateOfOrder has a fixed data type, some of them are date some of them are string in the same document, I would like to delete the whole document. The second way is to delete just to wrong date type, then the document will only delete the data type with string for that array value.  Thanks Wernfried!

Comment: Please provide a valid example. `db.collection.find()` should work at least.

Comment: The link has the sample data on the configuration side: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4izGcC2nsIf

I used the following query to find the data that is not date, it worked.  
db.Test.aggregate([
{$unwind: "$OrderDetail"},
  {$match: { 'OrderDetail.dateOfOrder': {$not : {$type: "date"}}}} 
])
It is when I used remove or pull to clean up the data, I am getting the error.

Comment: That's invalid input data!

Comment: Hmm, looks like the configuration file truncate the spaces between the data. It seems to be working with the deleteMany using the following script:

db.Test.deleteMany(
   { 'OrderDetail.dateOfOrder': {$not : {$type: "date"}}}
)

But it doesn't take care of the mixed data inside the array. Let me see whether I can paste the sample data below

Comment: {
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "OrderNumber" : "123",
    "OrderDetail" : [ 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type1",
            "dateOfOrder" : "Tue Jun 01 00:00:00 CDT 2021",
        }, 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type2",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-03-04T06:00:00.000Z"),
        }
    ]
}
{
    "ClientName" : "John",
    "OrderNumber" : "1234A",
    "OrderDetail" : [ 
        {
            "OrderDesc" : "Type1",
            "dateOfOrder" : ISODate("2021-06-01T05:00:00.000Z"),
        }       
    ]
}

Comment: The following code removes the fixed data inside the array :

db.Test.update(
  {},
  { $pull: {OrderDetail: { dateOfOrder:  {$not : {$type: "date"}}}} },
{ multi: true }
 );
So looks like running query to get the data I need to use aggregation but update and remove just simply using the query inside the condition.